# SharePont javascript client: How to ensure the correct sequence of the process?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, synchronization

I have a code where I read a record from a Sharepoint list and update that field to +1. But looks like the update sometime finish faster than the calculation of the input value so sometime the record value is not changed. Here is my code:

```
$(function ()
{
  $SP().list("TargetList","http://.../sites/Registry/").get(
  {
    where: "ID=1"            
  },
  function getData(data)
  {
    var calc = (Number(data[i].getAttribute("RecordToUpdate"))+Number("1"));
    alert(calc);
    $SP().list("TargetList","http://.../sites/Registry/").update({ID:1, RecordToUpdate: calc});
  });
});
```

So this is working nicly, but with about 10% chance the record is not updated I guess it is because sometime the update finish faster than the calculation of the `calc` variable (Sometime the `alert` appears with the default number of the `RecordToUpdate`, sometime `RecordToUpdate+1`). If I directly insert the calculation inside the update the fail chance is about 40%. So how can I force it to do the update only after the calculation for sure? 
Thanks you vey much for your kind help!

Comment: Being SharePoint, is this for IE users?

Comment: I don't know what browser ll be used by my users. I think chrome/IE is the most common. But I should make it works with all major browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Promise `.then` call to provide syncing!

```
$(function ()
{
  $SP().list("TargetList","http://.../sites/Registry/").get(
  {
    where: "ID=1"            
  },
  function getData(data)
  {
    var calc = (Number(data[i].getAttribute("RecordToUpdate"))+Number("1"));
    $SP().list("TargetList","http://.../sites/Registry/").update({ID:1, RecordToUpdate: calc}).then(function(){
      alert(calc);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I added it and looks like now working very well thank you very much! May I ask you to explan how it works? Even if the then.(function(){}) is empty, would be the same result or that alert there have a meaning? :) Sry for the noob question I am very new to JS. And thanks onece more!

Comment: @Nefri Since the `list.update` method has async nature, I've made an assumption that it should has a Promise based implementation. You may read about Promise patterns for example [here](https://www.promisejs.org/patterns/). So I was right, and the `list.update` method returns Promise, which means you can call `.then` to subscribe on the result of this call.

Comment: @Nefri The argument of `.then`-callback is the result of async `list.update` call, and you may work with it and do some logic around it, e.g. `.then(function(result) { if(isOkey(result) { console.log(result); }) })`

Comment: @Nefri At last, there is the second argument of `.then` which is fail callback. `.then(function(){ alert('success'); }, function(error){ alert(error); })`. PS I know nothing of Sharepoint, but I believe it should has a documentation with examples of Promise based syntax usage.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the clear explanations! Looks like I can use this for many things. I am going to dig in it. Very kind of you to helping me! :)